# Why would "Let us continue this in chat" 404?

Tags: discussion, comments, chat

I stumbled upon this question.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43791529/how-do-you-request-amazon-mws-api-info-within-a-laravel-app

The comments ended with

> Let us continue this discussion in chat. – Ohgodwhy

But that led to a 404

https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143543/discussion-between-ohgodwhy-and-pyreal

This makes me reluctant to use the continue in chat button in the future because I wouldn't want the discussion to get lost.

**What are some reasons a chat discussion would go 404?**

Comment: @HansPassant ah, well that's not great behavior I think ("Principle of least astonishment").  Should the link perhaps instead reflect this rather than give a generic 404?

Comment: @Hans - I'm seeing a well used chat room behind that link, but the chat room was "deleted for inactivity"? I was going to bring this up some time, it shouldn't be this way. That extended discussion could contain exactly the hint that some future Googler needs, and hiding it for everyone but 10k+ users seems nonsensical.

Comment: And this is why all the important information should be copied over the question/answer... not lie behind a link.

Comment: Yeah, I support what @Pekka웃 says. The room should have been frozen and not deleted. (Did that now). Funnily, if there are 3 or more users, the room is frozen for inactivity and not deleted. (I'm not that aware of the exact restrictions, I'll dig em up and write an answer)

Comment: @Braiam I don't see how that applies when the link is internal to the network though. How would I summarize a chat room conversation (often enough a "try this try that" debugging session) in an answer? We don't like people editing random info into existing answers, and a lot of small bits and pieces of information that can be *very* relevant to someone in the future don't pass the bar to being a good answer on their own. The simple solution is to not make chat rooms inaccessible to the public after a couple days.

Comment: @BhargavRao I happened to remember where they were stated and wrote an answer.

Comment: Feature request https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/349776/deleting-comment-generated-chat-rooms-is-dumb

Comment: @Pekka웃 if something important happened in chat... don't ya think it should be included on the question/answer?

Comment: On the up side, if you see a room like this that was deleted, you can always raise a flag and request for it to be undeleted, and frozen (or even unfrozen) instead. So it *is* a solvable issue, at least.

Comment: @Braiam `on't ya think it should be included on the question/answer?` of course, absolutely. But there's a lot of relevant side information that doesn't pass the bar for doing so.

Comment: @Pekka웃 "relevant information" and "important" are very close. Keyword: relevant.

Comment: 404 as a verb? It makes it close to incomprehensible for most readers.

Comment: @PeterMortensen Feel free to edit it instead of leaving a snarky comment

Comment: Don't threaten PeterMortensen with a good time, @Goose. :)

Answer (score 14):

The chat room was deleted.

As a moderator has undeleted the room this is no longer a problem for this specific chat room.

For future reference, the conditions for a room to be frozen or deleted are:

> A room is considered worth retaining if it has more than 15 messages by at least 2 users. [...]
> Rooms not worth retaining which are inactive for 7 days will be **deleted**. Rooms worth retaining which are inactive for 14 days will be **frozen**.

(source: https://chat.stackexchange.com/faq#retention)

This room had 12 messages, so it was not considered worth retaining.

Comment: Is it just me or does the link still go to a 404?

Comment: @numbermaniac It's not just for you, same here.

Comment: @numbermaniac Yes, but I'm sure it was undeleted yesterday. Let me guess.. the room still had less than 15 messages, so it was just deleted again.

Comment: @wythagoras That's exactly what happened. A mod undeleted and froze the room, and it was then almost immediately (a few hours) automatically deleted.

Comment: @Rob That doesn't seem very helpful; I'll post a feature request to change this.

Comment: lol..............

Comment: lol is right! Number of comments and age/activity are not valid criteria for determining the usefulness of a conversation. Even a single comment could contain a crucial key for understanding a question or answer. The only one who can evaluate that is a human, not a computer algorithm. So, instead of just leaving that content up, we're just deleting it? Yeah, I can see how that's helpful to the community.....