# Don't auto-delete chat rooms that were undeleted by a moderator

Tags: feature-request, chat

If a room was auto-deleted because of inactivity<sup>1</sup>, then undeleted by a moderator, it will be auto-deleted again the next day. This does not seem very helpful.

I propose that a room undeleted by a moderator should not be auto-deleted.

Note: this question comes from [Why would "Let us continue this in chat" 404?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/349728/why-would-let-us-continue-this-in-chat-404/)

<sup>1</sup> A room is considered worth retaining if it has more than 15 messages by at least 2 users.
 Rooms not worth retaining which are inactive for 7 days will be deleted.

Not a duplicate of [Deleting comment-generated chat rooms is counterproductive](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/349776/deleting-comment-generated-chat-rooms-is-counterproductive): That question asks to not delete them in the first place, this question makes a more general request for all chat rooms that were already undeleted by a moderator, that they are not deleted *again*.

Comment: @rene That question asks to not delete them in the first place, this question makes a more general request for all chat rooms that were already undeleted by a moderator, that they are not deleted *again*.

Comment: For that particular room, I added another message so now it won't be deleted again.

Comment: @BhargavRao eh... I guess it has been deleted again. Maybe one or two additional messages are needed. (I counted only 12 messages in the original room).

Comment: Err, wth. Co-incidently, if I type "Oh God why?" that's the first one to turn up in my browser history.